# Flex and polygonal.de graph classes in pathfinding?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, path-finding

I am wondering if someone have done this already, to send me into right direction..

- The issue is as follow : I have a 2 dimensional array, on which i hold integer numbers, if the number is 0 - the item shall not be included into the graph, if it is 1 - it must be included.
  The result graph shall be used for patfinding ( the shortest path ) to some element.
- how to turn this 2 dimensional array into the graph ? ( with polygona.de classes if possible ),

*I am currently trying with Polygonal.de classes. any suggestions and points into the right direction is more than appreciated.*

[image]

This is the 2 dimensional structure. The red cells is prohibited to walk on, and there must be found optimal path from "start" to the "end". But 1st things 1st - i need to turn this 2 dimensional structure into a graph now :|

Comment: Can you post a sketch or graphic to better visualize what you are describing?

Comment: hi @Jason Sturges . i have added a visual description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, your 2D array is already a graph. A node of the graph is represented by a pair `(i, j)` and may have neighbor nodes such as `(i + 1, j)`, `(i, j + 1)`, etc. You can write a utility function for your array that hides these low-level neighbor definitions and skips the cells that are occupied.

---

The [de.polygonal.ds API](http://www.polygonal.de/doc/ds/) for the [Graph](http://www.polygonal.de/doc/ds/types/de/polygonal/ds/Graph.html) data structure contains this example for the construction of a graph:

```
var graph = new de.polygonal.ds.Graph<String>();
var a = graph.addNode("a");
var b = graph.addNode("b");
var c = graph.addNode("c");
graph.addSingleArc(a, b, 1.0);
graph.addSingleArc(b, a, 1.0);
graph.addMutualArc(a, c, 1.0);
```

Adjust the example to construct a 2D array that contains a node for each free `(i, j)` of the original 2D array. Then traverse the 2D array of nodes and call `addMutualArc()` to connect adjacent nodes.

Comment: but how to create the actuall graph with polygonal.de classes ?

Comment: I got it... seems like i have missed this part. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: now i need to understand the role of this thing "cost" and "weight" of the nodes ..  :|